# Set eclipse hyperlink color under KDE

Tags: eclipse, themes, gnome, kde-plasma

I have dark eclipse theme (Moonrise) and also dark theme for native widgets set in KDE. The problem is that dar blue hyperlink are not very legible so I would like them to be of different color. In the picture there is not that dark theme used, but with darker colors the link cannot be read.
[image]

Even thoughtI was setting the hyperlink color in every possible settings menu I could think of, I have not been able to set eclipse hyperlink color. It seems that Eclipse ignored the `Appearance -> Colors and fonts` settings.

[image]

It would make somehow sense if the native GUI settings would be to have dark blue hyperlink color. But I cannot see, that this would be the case in `Application Appearance -> Colors` section.

[image]

Is there a way to change the color of hyperlink? Why is it still dark blue? I am not interested in settings the tooltip background as is often suggested in this case- I have already set it to lighter color so the hyperlinks are readable.

Comment: I remember having this same problem and I also remember I wasn't able to find a solution. :(

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

- Go to Window > Preferences and change the current theme restart eclipse. Refer picture below.

[image]

- Install eclipse colour theme plugin then you will get lots of options to change the theme. See [here](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org).

Note that in different themes the colour of active and visited link will be different.

#### Edit

After looking at your comment, you may get some clues from here

[GNOME settings](http://www.linuxandlife.com/2011/11/edit-link-colors-in-gtk-themes.html)

[KDE settings](https://askubuntu.com/a/222936/112794)

[Eclipse on Ubuntu](http://blog.vogella.com/2012/12/04/eclipse-papercut-10-eclipse-on-ubuntu-fixing-the-black-background-color-in-hover/)

Comment: I think you are mixing widget theme with editor theme. Your link is to editor themes. I am already using the oblivion one. But links are displayed not in editor but in widgets.